# Can sIFR work with Smarty templates?

Tags: javascript, image, fonts, sifr, smarty

I have WHMCS installed, and am editing the templates (Smarty).  I cannot get the sIFR js to work.  I have read all the relevant questions here, and I've read the tutorials on sIFR v. 2 and v.3.  Right now I'm on hte latest nightly build with sIFR so that I can use the font.  I did however, generate the font online stead of using a flash editor.  I still have a font.swf file - does it matter?

I don't know a lick of js, and I've tried all day to get the other js (cochon?) working - no dice.

Would love some pointers!!

Thank you.

Comment: Look at your question and ask yourself if someone can seriously help you with what you have provided. Have you tried a basic page to test sifr on? What's your HTML look like? Your javascript? How are we supposed to know what's wrong with seeing some code?

Answer (score 0):

In my experience sIFR is much more trouble than it is really worth - I use Cufon, and provided you keep your usage fairly low (it can slow down IE if it is overdone) you shouldn't have any problems.  Setting it up is fairly easy too, just

1: Convert your font here - http://cufon.shoqolate.com/generate/

2: Download cufon.js and save it with your font - https://github.com/sorccu/cufon/wiki/about

3: Link to them in your HTML

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/cufon-yui.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/Pointy_400.font.js"></script>
```

4: Apply the font to the elements (in head tag)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    Cufon('h2')('h3')('h4')
</script>
```

Done!

Answer (score 0):

sIFR works on the client side, on the resulting HTML output. So the answer is yes, because Smarty doesn't matter.